# Password in apps script for Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, passwords

I'm in charge of making restricted access to a Google Sheets file and all the sheets within it.

My code works but when the user clicks outside the password box, the password box closes and the script stops running so the password is no longer asked for until the file is closed and reopened.

Help to keep the script running always, even if there are sequence errors, until the password is entered. Thank you.

```
function contrasena() {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
  var codigoCorrecto = "Centro Victoria" 
  var guardarIntento = "" 

  while (guardarIntento != codigoCorrecto) {
    guardarIntento = ui.prompt("Por favor ingrese la contraseña").getResponseText();
  } 
  ui.alert("Contraseña Confirmada");
}
```

In another `onOpen` function I created the initializer.Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot block access to a spreadsheet by installing a script.

Google Apps Script runs on Google's servers rather than in your computer. You can certainly create a very annoying dialog box that comes back again and again, but it will not stop a determined user from discovering all contents of the spreadsheet. For example, they can create another spreadsheet and use the `importrange()` function to read the data in the spreadsheet you are trying to protect.

Further, scripts only run for users who have edit access to the spreadsheet. These users also have the right to view and modify any scripts installed in the spreadsheet. If your script project is in **Extensions > Apps Script**, they can just look at the code to find the password you have assigned.

The correct way to control who can view and edit a spreadsheet is to use **File > Share > Share with others > Restricted**.

Comment: But isn't there a way to block a certain part of the keyboard and/or limit the movement of the mouse to a certain region of the screen so that the dialog box cannot be exited so easily until a correct answer is given?

Comment: No, that cannot be done with Google Apps Script. Edited the answer to add details.